# find_library or link_directories or find_package? What is better way? Error - Link libraries using cmake

Tags: cmake, gstreamer, dynamic-linking, shared-libraries

**Given**
The file `/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so` is present
Making changes in CMakeLists.txt

**Approach 1**   `find_library()`

> find_library(GST_FFMPEG NAMES gstffmpeg PATHS /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/ )
>   ...
>   target_link_libraries( MyLibraryOrMyExecutable ${GST_FFMPEG} )

When I run `make` with above configuration(approach 1), I get the following errors

> /bin/ld: warning: **libvpx.so.1**, needed by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /bin/ld: warning: **libschroedinger-1.0.so.0**, needed by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /bin/ld: warning: **libgsm.so.1**, needed by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

Looks like the added library depends on more libraries which are not linked! I can see above 3 .so files in /usr/lib. So one possible solution to approach 1 could be to add three more `find_library()` functions. right ?

May be not- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880532/so-with-numerals-after-that-how-to-match-them-in-find-library-in-cmake-error) explores the issues found in above possible solution

- Q1. Is there any other method which saves the effort of finding the
  dependent libraries and linking them ? An approach using which all the dependent libraries get automatically linked ?

**Approach 2** `link_directories()`

> link_directories(/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/)
>   target_link_libraries( MyLibraryOrMyExecutable gstffmpeg )

When I run `make` with above configuration(approach 2), I get the following errors

> bin/ld: cannot find -lgstffmpeg

- Q2. How to solve the issue with above approach 2?
- Q3. Which approach 1 or 2 is better ?

P.S. Tried reading documentation for cmake and searching on SO but could not resolve my problem. 
I tried two approaches and have issues with both them

Answer (score 1):

To answer your Q3 first, I think the preferred method is approach 1.

From the docs for [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories):

> Note that this command is rarely necessary. Library locations returned by find_package() and find_library() are absolute paths. Pass these absolute library file paths directly to the target_link_libraries() command. CMake will ensure the linker finds them.

Regardless of the approach you take, I don't know of an easy way to automatically get the list of these "sub-dependencies" and add them.  I'd just do a `find_package` or `find_library` for each.

At least that way, if a dependency isn't found, your project fails at CMake configure time rather than at link time.

Comment: This seems to conflict with the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821133/1447953

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar scenario, I solve it by add in CMakesList.txt, just before find_library(), add this command:

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /the/path/to/your/lib/)

，but normally if your dependencies libraries are in usr/lib or usr/local/lib paths, it could find by well called the functions.