# .so with numerals after that, how to match them in find_library in cmake ? Error in linking shared objects which are found as sub-dependencies

Tags: cmake, gstreamer, dynamic-linking, shared-objects, shared-libraries

**Given**
`ls -lrt /usr/lib/libvpx*` results

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Feb  9  2012 /usr/lib/libvpx.so.1.0 ->libvpx.so.1.0.0
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Feb  9  2012 /usr/lib/libvpx.so.1 -> libvpx.so.1.0.0
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 646120 Feb  9  2012 /usr/lib/libvpx.so.1.0.0

`ls -lrt /usr/lib/libschroedinger*` results

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     29 Feb  8  2012 /usr/lib/libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 ->libschroedinger-1.0.so.0.11.0
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 774044 Feb  8  2012 /usr/lib/libschroedinger-1.0.so.0.11.0

`ls -lrt /usr/lib/libgsm*` results

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Nov  5  2009 /usr/lib/libgsm.so.1 -> libgsm.so.1.0.12
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50680 Nov  5  2009 /usr/lib/libgsm.so.1.0.12

This is a possible solution to issues found in Approach 1 of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857000/link-libraries-using-cmake-what-is-the-exact-way-what-should-we-use-find-libra). You may/ may not refer that.

**Possible Solution**
As I mentioned in the parent question, we may need to add three `find_library()` functions. Below are contents from CMakeLists.txt

*possible solution 1a*

> find_library(VPX_LIBRARIES NAMES libvpx.so.1 PATHS /usr/lib/ )
>   find_library(SCHROEDINGER_LIBRARIES NAMES libschroedinger-1.0.so.0-1.0 PATHS /usr/lib/)
>   find_library(GSM_LIBRARIES NAMES libgsm.so.1 PATHS /usr/lib/ )
>
> target_link_libraries(MyLibraryOrMyExecutable ${VPX_LIBRARIES} ${SCHROEDINGER_LIBRARIES} ${GSM_LIBRARIES} )

*possible solution 1b*

> find_library(VPX_LIBRARIES NAMES vpx PATHS /usr/lib/)
>   find_library(SCHROEDINGER_LIBRARIES NAMES schroedinger-1.0 PATHS
>   /usr/lib/)     find_library(GSM_LIBRARIES NAMES gsm PATHS /usr/lib/)
>
> target_link_libraries(MyLibraryOrMyExecutable ${VPX_LIBRARIES} ${SCHROEDINGER_LIBRARIES} ${GSM_LIBRARIES} )

**Error**
I get the same error for both the solutions 1a and 1b

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files:
>
> GSM_LIBRARIES
>       linked by target "MyLibraryOrMyExecutable" in directory /someDirectory
>
> SCHROEDINGER_LIBRARIES
>       linked by target "MyLibraryOrMyExecutable" in directory /someDirectory
>
> VPX_LIBRARIES
>       linked by target "MyLibraryOrMyExecutable" in directory /someDirectory

cmake looks for libvpx.so after reading vpx in NAMES from find_library(), but find a different file like libvpx.so.1 hence I used 1b too where I have given the exact names. But still no luck.

**Q** How do one resolve an issue like this where the name of the shared objects also include a number after the extension, and the exact name does not match with the name given in `find_library()`. ?  I tried to give the exact names, that also does not work

Answer (score 7):

Command [find_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) use [CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES) and [CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES) variables to glue the real library name. For instance:

```
> cat CMakeLists.txt
message("suffixes: ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}")
message("prefixes: ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}")
> cmake -H. -B_builds
suffixes: .so;.a
prefixes: lib
```

[CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES) is a list variable and you can add a new suffix:

```
> cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
list(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .so.17)
find_library(library edata-book-1.2)
message("library: ${library}")
> cmake -H. -B_builds
library: /usr/lib/libedata-book-1.2.so.17
```

**But** I'm pretty sure that the **real** problem here is package manager usage (: Usually
`lib<name>.so` is a symlink to `lib<name>.so.N.M` file. So I recommend you to check manuals
and install your library in an appropriate way.