# "No rule to make target" error in cmake when linking to shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, libraries

In Ubuntu, I have downloaded a third-party shared library, `mylibrary.so`, which I have placed in the directory `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries`. I have also placed the associated header file, `myheader.h`, in the directory `/home/karnivaurus/Headers`. I now want to link to this library in my C++ code, using CMake. Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.0.0)

project(DemoProject)

include_directories(/home/karnivaurus/Headers)

add_executable(demo demo.cpp)

target_link_libraries(demo /home/karnivaurus/Libraries/mylibrary)
```

However, this gives me the error message:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/mylibrary', needed by `demo'.  Stop.
```

What's going on?

Comment: 1. Do you really need to support CMake as **ancient** as 2.0? 2. Shouldn't the library's name on disk be `libmylibrary.so`? If it's not, you might try adding the `.so` extension to `target_link_libraries()`, it might help unconfuse it.

Comment: If I add the `.so` extension, it then gives me the error: `cannot find -lmylibrary`

Comment: Can you link to the library manually, i.e. in a project not using CMake? If so, what command line achieves that? It might be possible to infer the CMake syntax from this. I still believe the library's name does not follow Linux conventions, though.

Comment: Are you missing an add_library call?

Comment: Doesn't `add_library` build a new library from source? I have already been given the compiled `mylibrary.so` file...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Answer (score 7):

While the other answer posted here is valid, it is out-dated. CMake now provides better solutions for using a pre-built external library in your code. In fact, CMake itself even discourages the use of [`link_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/link_directories.html) in its documentation.

The `target_link_libraries()` command takes very specific syntax for linking to an external library. A more modern solution is to create an `IMPORTED` CMake target for your external library:

```
add_library(MyExternalLib SHARED IMPORTED)

# Provide the full path to the library, so CMake knows where to find it.
set_target_properties(MyExternalLib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/karnivaurus/Libraries/mylibrary.so)
```

You can then use this imported CMake target later on in your code, and *link* it to your other targets:

```
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE MyExternalLib)
```

For other ways to use an external third-party library in your CMake code, see the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774593/3987854).

Comment: @astronomerdave The [`IMPORTED_LOCATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) property should point to a single target. I believe you can set two *versions* of a library for one target, using `IMPORTED_LOCATION_Debug` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION_Release`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a full path to the static library. To link w/ dynamic one, better to use `link_directories()` like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.0.0)

project(DemoProject)

include_directories(/home/karnivaurus/Headers)
link_directories(/home/karnivaurus/Libraries)

add_executable(demo demo.cpp)

target_link_libraries(demo mylibrary)
```

and make sure `mylibrary` has prefix `lib` and suffix `.so` in file name (i.e. full name is `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/libmylibrary.so`).

To make you project more flexible, you'd better to write a [*finder module*](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) and avoid hardcode paths like `/home/karnivaurus/*`

Comment: Use find_file and friends instead.

Comment: @steveire often just having some path to a file is not enough. for more serious projects it is better to learn finders and how to write them.

Comment: That's not your suggestion.

Comment: This answer is very outdated. The current CMake documentation explicitly states that `link_directories` should be avoided. Refer to the documentation for more information on alternatives.

Comment: I don't consider it a waste of time and I'm not trying to insult your answer. I'm not saying it was a bad answer when it was written, but people will stumble across this thread on Google looking for CMake advice. They should be made aware that although it may have been a good answer in the past it would be bad to take this advice today because there are better alternatives.